# The Proximal Operator of a Function with $ {L}_{1} $ Norm and Affine Term

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I want to solve the following minimization problem: ($G(x)=\lambda||Ax+b||_1$)
$$ prox_{\tau G}(x^k) = \arg\min_z \frac{1}{2\tau} ||z-x^k||_2^2 + \lambda||Az + b||_1  $$

---

I know how to calculate in the case of L1-norm and translation. ($G(x)=\lambda ||x-g||_1$ for a constant vector $g$)
$$ prox_{\tau G}(x^k) = \arg\min_z \frac{1}{2\tau} ||z-x^k||_2^2 + \lambda||z-g||_1 $$

Let $z-g=y$, then
$$ y^{k+1} = \arg\min_y \frac{1}{2\tau} ||y-(x^k-g)||_2^2 + \lambda||y||_1 \\ = shrink(x^k-g,\tau\lambda)$$

where $$ shrink(y,\alpha)=sgn(y)\max(|y|-\alpha,0)=\begin{cases}y-\alpha & y\in(\alpha,\infty)\\
0&y\in[-\alpha,\alpha]\\
y+\alpha & y\in(-\infty,-\alpha)\end{cases} $$

So $$x^{k+1}:= z^{k+1} = g + y^{k+1}\\ x^{k+1} = g+ shrink(x^k-g,\tau\lambda) $$

---

But I don't know how to solve when $G(z) = \lambda ||Az+b||_1$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no known closed form expression for this (unless $ A $ has some special structure such as orthogonality). If there were a closed form expression for this, it would be extremely useful in convex optimization.

To evaluate this prox-operator, you would have to solve the optimization problem using some numerical method.

But why do you need to evaluate this prox-operator? You can use proximal algorithms in a way that decouples $ A$ from the $1$-norm.

Edit: One important example of special structure in $A$ is when $A A^T = \lambda I$.  In this case, the prox-operator can be evaluated using the technique in slide 8-8 of Vandenberghe's 236c notes:  http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/proxop.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, I see in page 42 at http://www.icg.tugraz.at/courses/lv710.080/info/motion_estimation.pdf . In that case, there seems to have a structure.

Comment: I want to calculate TV-L1 optical flow similar to the formula in the above pdf file.

Comment: Ah, yes,  $ A$ has a very simple structure in that example. That's a key point.

Comment: After studying, I can know how to derive the formula in the above pdf file. In this case, $A=\nabla I$ (gradient of image). But I am confused why it can be derived by simple calculus and what the structure is.

Comment: @jakeoung, It would be nice if you shared your insights.

Comment: Excuse me, you are still have the pdf file that you mentioned (icg.tugraz.at/courses/lv710.080/info/motion_estimation.pdf ) because I want to check the proof for it. Thank you.