# The Sub Gradient and the Proximal Operator of ${L}_1$ Norm with Metric

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I want to solve the optimization:

$$\arg\underset{x}{\min}f(x) = \arg\underset{x}{\min}\lambda\lVert Mx\rVert_1 + \frac{1}{2}\lVert x-y\rVert_2^2$$

Where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (a positive semi-definite matrix representing a metric in my case).

Taking n=2 as example, after trying to develop the sub gradient of this target function I got (for component $x_1$) :
$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x_1}}=\sum_{i=1}^2 m_{i1}\ \text{sign}(m_{i1}x_1 + m_{i2}x_2)+(x_1-y_1)$$

By following the derivation of $L_1$ regularized least squares (ref. https://angms.science/doc/CVX/ISTA0.pdf), we can draw polylines in $x_1x_2$ plane for a $y$ value, and finally find the intersection point where $\vec{0}\in\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$.

But this method is hard to be generalized to 3D and higher dimension. I'm looking forward to some general solutions.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no general formula for the prox of a function composed with a linear operator. You can have a formula if you consider semi orthogonal matrices though.

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki appreciate, and I did find some guide on that : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481071/the-proximal-operator-of-a-function-with-l-1-norm-and-affine-term?rq=1